# How to bring four columns of excel data as two rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have data in four columns in excel, to be transposed to two rows.
The first column to be the header row for the data in the second column and the third column to be the header for the data in the fourth column as below:

The data is as below

```
A    1      G   7
B    2      H   8
C    3      I   9
D    4      J   10
E    5      K   11
F    6      L   12
```

And need to transpose

```
A  B  C D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L
1  2  3 4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
```

Appreciating your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`transpose(.T)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
In [2139]: d = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :2].T.reset_index(drop=True), df.iloc[:, 2:].T.reset_index(drop=True)],1)

In [2144]: d.columns = d.loc[0]

In [2147]: d = d.drop(0)

In [2148]: d
Out[2148]: 
0  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J   K   L
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: Thank you @Mayank Porwal

Answer (score 2):

For general solution working with `4`, `6`, `10` columns select pairs and unpairs columns by indexing, flatten in numpy array and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
c = df.iloc[:, ::2].T.to_numpy().ravel()
v = df.iloc[:, 1::2].T.to_numpy().ravel()

df = pd.DataFrame([v], columns=c)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J   K   L
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Or if want use pandas solution create `MultiIndex` by modulo and integer division of `np.arange` by length of columns and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then transpose and some data cleaning:

```
a = np.arange(len(df.columns))

df.columns = [a % 2, a // 2]
df = (df.stack()
        .sort_index(level=1)
        .set_index(0)[[1]]
        .T
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J   K   L
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.reshape`, `np.vstack`, and then `set_index` and `Transpose`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(np.split(df, 2, axis=1))).set_index(0).T

0  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J   K   L
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: Awesome. That is wonderful. I tried all three solutions. I am a novice to python and programming as a whole. This was my first question here and I got a very good response. Thank you, @Sayandip Dutta

Comment: @ArifKassim you are welcome. At SO, if you ask decent question you will almost always get help. If this works, you may consider upvoting.